# Cloud functions -

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Node.js 8 now and Firebase cloud functions version 2.0.0.

I have problem now with this new version because there are some breaking changes.

My problem is that i wrote a method that listen to a node in Firebase Realtime Database when a new child is added.
This method is triggered and then sends data to another node in the database.

**Code**

```
exports.addlikechange = functions.database.ref('/likes/{postid}/{userUID}').onWrite((change,context) => {
    const model = change.after.val();

    let genre = model.genre;
    let videoID = model.videoID;
    let userVideoID = model.userVideoID;

    console.log("Start func","--------> Start Like Count <----- ");
    console.log("model: ",model);
    console.log("genre: ",genre);
    console.log("videoId: ",videoID);
    console.log("userVideoID: ",userVideoID);

    const countRef = collectionRef.child('likes');


    // Return the promise from countRef.transaction() so our function 
    // waits for this async event to complete before it exits.
     return countRef.transaction(current => {
      if (change.data.exists() && !change.data.previous.exists()) {
        const genreList = admin.database().ref(`${genre}/${videoID}/likes`).transaction(current => {
          return (current || 0) + 1;
        });
        const userList = admin.database().ref(`users/${userVideoID}/likes`).transaction(current => {
          return (current || 0) + 1;
        });
        const videoList = admin.database().ref(`videos/${userVideoID}/${videoID}/likes`).transaction(current => {
          return (current || 0) + 1;
        });
      }
     }).then(() => {
       console.log('Counter updated.');
       console.log("End func","--------> End Like Count <----- ");
     });
   });
```

The problem is with the `collectionRef` , in the logcat it says that collectionRef is not defined. But as you can see, it is defined.

**Full error**

```
ReferenceError: collectionRef is not defined
    at exports.addlikechange.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:60:36)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:120:23)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:151:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:827:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Any idea what changed or how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're saying isn't true - `collectionRef` was never defined.  You're attempting to use something called `collectionRef`, it but you never assigned it a value.  You need to do something like this:

```
const collectionRef = ...   // whatever reference you need to use here
```

Comment: Well that code worked before they change to version 2.0.0. What im trying to do is just update a node in the `firebase database realtime`. Any idea what should i do so it will work again?

Answer (score 0):

As what the answer above mentioned, I don't see collectionRef defined anywhere as well.

But I think what broke your (if it was working before, despite the undefined collectionRef) code was, installing node 8 will automatically enable strict config in your `tsconfig.json`.

But you can also do this to disable enforcement of any undefined variable:

Add on `"strict": false,` to your `tsconfig.json` file like so:

```
 {
    "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "target": "es2015"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```